# How to Vectorize `[`

Tags: r, vectorization

I'm having trouble getting `Vectorize` to work with `[`, getting the error shown below.  From the `help("[")` it seems like `[` has arguments named `x`, `i`, and `j` - but they don't seem to work when I used them as `vectorize.args`.  Can I do this?

```
## Some data
dat <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=11:20, c=21:30)

## Vectorize with mapply, seems to work
f <- function(i, j, dat) list(dat[i, j])
mapply(f, list(1:2, 3:4), list(1:2, 2:3), MoreArgs = list(dat=dat))
# [[1]]
#   a  b
# 1 1 11
# 2 2 12
# 
# [[2]]
#    b  c
# 3 13 23
# 4 14 24

## Now using Vectorize, apply to data
Vectorize(`[`, c("i", "j"))(x=dat, i=list(1:2, 2:3), j=list(1:2, 2:3))
```

> Error in Vectorize(`[`, c("i", "j")) : 
>     must specify names of formal arguments for 'vectorize'

But, this works (with a warning for naming the arguments)

```
`[`(x=dat, i=1:2, j=1:2)
```

Also, if I do this, it's ok

```
Vectorize(`[.data.frame`, c("i", "j"))(dat, list(1:2, 2:3), list(1:2, 2:3))
```

Comment: `[` is a primitive, and doesn't have named formal arguments, ie `formals("[") NULL`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Vectorize()` is documented to not be usable with **primitive** functions. From `?Vectorize`

```
 ‘Vectorize’ cannot be used with primitive functions as they do not
 have a value for ‘formals’.
```

And `[` is a primitive in R:

```
> `[`
.Primitive("[")
```

As `[` is already vectorized I don't see the point of even trying this. The usual idiom for your `` `[`(x=dat, i=1:2, j=1:2) `` is simply:

```
dat[1:2, 1:2]

> dat[1:2, 1:2]
  a  b
1 1 11
2 2 12
```

This indices can be (pre-existing) objects too:

```
i <- 1:2
j <- 1:2
dat[i, j]

> dat[i, j]
  a  b
1 1 11
2 2 12
```

If you have more than one set of extractions, then I suppose you could call the `[.data.frame` method directly in `Vectorise`. The examples for `?Vectorize` illustrate doing this sort of thing for function `rep()`, which is primitive, so uses `rep.int()` instead.

Comment: @nongkrong primitve functions *don't* have formals, so you can't get them. If you could get them, `Vectorize` would work. See the relevant section of the [R Internals Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive)